# No such file or directory error

Tags: shell, ksh

```
counter=0
if [ ${counter} < 10 ]; then
  echo 10
fi
```

error : no such file or directory.

What wrong in there ?

Comment: `<` is not a `[` operator. You want `-lt`. `<` is for input redirection. That error should `10` in it somewhere though.

Comment: Here `if [ ${counter} < 10 ]; then` is the same as `if [ ${counter} ] < 10; then` and `if test ${counter} < 10; then`.

Comment: If you want an arithmetic comparison, use `if (( counter < 10 )); then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the < symbol (which is for shell redirection) you need to use the -lt option to test.

```
counter=0
if [ ${counter} -lt 10 ]; then
  echo 10
fi
```

With the <, the shell is actually trying to read in a file named 10 to stdin of the command `[ ${counter}` (aka `test ${counter}`).

`man test` is one of those things I constantly refer back to just to reassure myself.