# How to change the index values to start from 0

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

```
rolling_window = 120
df = df.rolling(rolling_window, min_periods=1).agg(['mean','std'])
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
# df = df.reset_index()
df = df.iloc[(rolling_window-1):,]
df = df.rename_axis('timestamps').reset_index()
df = df.set_index('timestamps')
```

the dataframe get index position start from 119 but I want to start from 0. how to reset?

Comment: you can see :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332024/no-such-file-or-directory-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32249984/5226470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The `drop` attribute specifies whether the previously used index column should be removed.

Comment: I just have to keep `timestamp` as index position but it start from 119 so just I want to start from 0 to len(df)

Comment: So, you want your index column to be named as 'timestamps'? And the values of this column are from 0 to number of rows - 1?

Comment: yes. I want the timestamp as index column

Comment: Try this: 
df['timestamp'] = list(range(df.shape[0]))
df.set_index('timestamp')